# $Nx = \prod \sigma(x)$ where $\sigma$ runs over the Galois group $G = Gal(F_q/F_p)$. Prove that $N$ is surjective.

Tags: galois-theory

Let $F_q$ be the finite field with $q = p^n$ elements and let $N: F_q \to F_p$ be the norm map, defined by
$$Nx = \prod \sigma(x)$$

where $\sigma$ runs over the Galois group $G = Gal(F_q/F_p)$. Prove that $N$ is surjective.

**My solution:** The degree of the extension $F_q/F_p$ is $n$, so the Galois group has $n$ elements. The Frobenius automorphism $x\mapsto x^p$ is clearly one such element of the Galois group. Letting $\sigma^k$ be composition by $\sigma$ $k$ times, we have  for $k<n$, $\sigma^k(x) = x^{p^k}\neq x$. Therefore, $\sigma^k$ is not the identity map. Consequently, $\sigma^0, \sigma^1,\ldots,\sigma^n$ are all distinct so $G = \langle \sigma \rangle$. Thus
$$Nx = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\sigma^i(x) =\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}x^{p^i} = x^{1 + p + \cdots + p^{n-1}} = x^{\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}}$$

However, I can't seem to see why this must be surjective.

Comment: What does it give you for $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: And if $\mu_x$ is of degree $n$, you get $\mu_x(0) = (-1)^n Nx$

Comment: Hint: It could be useful to use the fact that the group of units of $\mathbb{F}_q$ is cyclic.

Comment: I know that $x^q = x^{p^n} = 1$ when $x \in \mathbb{F}_q$. However, the exponent of $x$ in my expression is $\frac{p^n - 1}{p-1}$ which is neither a multiple nor a divisor of $p^n$. Unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$. Then $\mathbb F_p=\{x\in K:x^p=x\}$ and $\mathbb F_q=\{x\in K:x^q=x\}$. Now, what you are asking is: for any $x\in K$ such that $x^p=x$, is there a $y\in K$ such that $y^q=y$ and $y^{(q-1)/(p-1)}=x$?

Let $y\in K$ be a $\frac{q-1}{p-1}$-th root of $x$, which exists since $K$ is algebraically closed. All that you need to check now is that $y^q=y$. This is fairly straightforward, so I leave it to you as an exercise.